# Check if data set is drawn from a distribution/Check if sample is representative

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample

I have a data set $X$ and there is another sample $Y$. I suspect that $Y$ is a subsample of $X$ and I want to check that hypothesis. Obviously, both contain the same number of variables (data types are `char`, `int`, and `numeric`). For the numeric variable I could easily use the KS-test to check the distribution of $X$ against the distribution of $Y$.

But what about the `char` and the `int` variable? Another problem is that testing the variables individually would lead to a higher probability of an erroneous decision (multiple hypothesis problem). Is there a way of testing wether a whole data set was drawn from a larger data set?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "subsample" and "drawn from"? Those terms typically imply the observations in $Y$ all appear in $X$--and establishing that is a matter of applying a simple matching algorithm, not of performing distribution tests.  This makes me suspect you might have in mind a different concept of "subsample."

Comment: yes, all observations in $Y$ appear in $X$. But I want to test wether $Y$ is really a random sample from $X$ and not a deterministic draw (e.g. $Y = $ all observations from $X$ for which the `numeric` variable is between 0 and 5. — this would be clearly no random sample).
Could you elaborate a little more on how this could be stated as a mathcing problem? I don't see that at all. Thank yoU!

Comment: One solution is to look up each row from $Y$ within the table $X$ (after first sorting or indexing $X$).  This algorithm takes time proportional to $O((|Y| + |X|) \log(|X|)),$ which is efficient.  Testing for randomness requires you to specify patterns you think are non-random.  After all--by the very definition of a uniformly random sample--*every* possible $Y$ is equally "random." There is no way after the fact to demonstrate that any sample was obtained randomly.

Comment: Ah I see your point. But I unfortunately made that not clear enough: What I am (only) interested in is wether $Y$ is representative for $X$, that is, if I calculated something like the KL-divergence or the KS-statistic, I would not reject my null hypothesis if the value is small (because then the distributions are very similar).

Comment: Fair enough--but the same issue lurks, because "representative" can be defined only with respect to a set of properties of interest.  After the fact, you can *always* find some property any non-exhaustive sample does not share with its population.